# 'Make recommendations on how to...'

Tags: prepositions

I've written this sentence:

> Please **make recommendations on how to** improve language skills.

Is it a valid/good language construct? I'm confused about which preposition to use. I've found examples with 'on', 'about', 'to' and 'for'.

Which preposition should I use? Is there a better way to phrase it?

Comment: Can you clarify why you think it might not be valid?

Comment: I was not sure about which is correct: 'on', 'about', 'to' or 'for' as I can find examples of every of these, but i'm not sure when to use which.

Comment: 'On' and 'for' are both good. I might use one or the other depending on random chance as much as anything else. 'About' can work as well, but doesn't flow quite as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Make recommendations on how to" in that sentence is **perfectly fine.**

Another way you could phrase it would be

> Please make **some** recommendations on how to ...

But they mean the same thing.

The only thing I think you might want to change, depending on what you really want to say, would be later in the phrase. If you're asking about *your* language skills in particular, you really should specify that:

> Please make recommendations on how to improve **my** language skills.

Or "our language skills", "her language skills", etc. In this case it would be considered normal to say whose language skills you're asking about. If you don't say whose, that will probably be heard as intentional: that you *aren't* asking about a specific person's language skills, but about any person's language skills. For example, when a teacher is asking, but isn't thinking about any students in particular.

Comment: +1, If we're going to suggest better phrasings, I would go with "Please make some recommendations on/for/about *improving* my language skills" or "Please *recommend* how to improve my language skills".

Comment: @DCShannon yes, both of those sound more natural to me, too.